# Django: Proper way to display options to the user in this case

Tags: django, user-interface, django-templates

**EDIT**
Why would you downvote this question? Is there any question on SO that answers this that would show i didn't try to find it or google has answer to it that I missed? Or this is not the proper place to ask such questions?
This is a simple question asking for advice on how to display options keeping MY particular data structure in mind.
Please mention the reason for downvote.

**ORIGINAL**

I am trying to make my first website. I am using Django for it.

I need advice from you people regarding UI of a portion of my template.

I have a doctor user who will have to choose his clinic timings. So he has to choose from 7 days of week. Each day will have three shifts(Morning, Afternoon, Evening).

He may choose 1 or more days and then for each day he may choose 1 or more shifts and provide time for each shift.

How should I go about making options available to him so that it is easier for him to choose days-shifts-time and at the same time not clutter the UI?

One way is to display all 7 days then under each day display three shift and for each shift show time field. But I think this is too much on a `modal` popup.

Can you please suggest anything to make it simpler or show any screenshot from any site etc to get an idea about this.

To get an idea how my data is, you can refer to the image
[image: here]

Answer (score 0):

I assume the "Clinic X" tables in your picture are actually m2m intermediary through tables? Meaning they contain a foreign key to both the doctor and clinic tables? I think to remember this from yesterday, when you still had an excerpt of your models.py in your post (I wanted to ask for more details, but I dont have the rep to comment yet).

You could make a view based on the "Clinic X" models. It would contain ModelChoice fields for selecting the right clinic and the doctor (or, if the doctor is actually the USER responsible for creating the data, have the doctor be fixed by checking request.user).
Then you could employ inlineformsets for the selection of days and start times.

If the 'shifts' are not mandatory, I would drop them entirely. You would have to code in checks that the user does not begin his afternoon shift at 2 am, etc.

Also, while I appreciate MS Paint art... you should try to model this with something like UML. While modelling may seem like a waste of time at first, they really help you understand your own project.

Comment: I did it  like this for now:

<br/>
Clinic Dropdown. <br/>

Morning Shift: <br/>
Days-Dropdown ------------- Timepicker <br/>

Afternoon Shift: <br/>
Days-Dropdown ------------- Timepicker <br/>

Evening Shift: <br/>
Days-Dropdown ------------- Timepicker. <br/>


That Seems ok for now. 

I will try to optimize and fix minor issues after more testing once I get this project started. 

Thanks for the suggestions.